# How to load different webpage depending upon screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two different webpages. One is for phones/tablets and the other is for desktops. I want to display one of the webpages depending upon the device being used. I cannot use media queries as the content is different in both of them. Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Assign to `window.location` depending on the size.

Comment: are you using any server side scripting ? if yes than you can do it in that. like in PHP by checking. - $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript

```
if(screen.width < 991)
    window.location = 'mobilepage.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { /* do what you want */ }
```

EDIT:

For the loading you should use this
window.location = 'mobile.html';

Answer (score -1):

You should use a libraries to scale your page, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a very popular one. Basicly it gives you classes to add to you site element and it will scale it. You should really use this instead of two seperate website, it will make the maintenance easier.